# How do i continue, where did i get it wrong?

Tags: python

the question:

> Give numBottles(input) full water bottles, you can
> exchange numExchange(input) empty bottles for one full water bottle.
> The operation of drinking a full water bottle turns it into an empty
> bottle. Return the maximum number of water bottles you can drink. No
> functions, imports, whatsoever, only list, string, int, loops and that
> kinda stuff.
>
> Ex.1:
>
> Input(s): numBottles = 9, numExchange = 3 Output: 13 Explanation: You
> can exchange 3 empty bottles to get 1 full water bottle. Number of
> water bottles you can drink: 9+3+1 = 13
>
> Ex.2: Input(s) :numbottles = 15, numexchange = 4 Output: 19
> Explanation: You can exchange 4 empty bottles to get 1 full water
> bottle. Number of water bottles you can drink: 15 + 3 + 1 = 19

What i have gotten:

```
    Numbottles = int(input("Numbottles"))
    Numexchange = int(input("NumExchange"))
    total = []
    for i in range(0,Numbottles // Numexchange):
            x = Numbottles % Numexchange
            total.append(x)
    print(sum(total))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
Numbottles = int(input("Numbottles"))
Numexchange = int(input("NumExchange"))
total = [Numbottles]
for i in range(0,Numbottles // Numexchange):
        Numbottles = Numbottles // Numexchange
        total.append(Numbottles)
        Numbottles += Numbottles % Numexchange
print(sum(total))
```